# C# pinvoke C char array

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Marshalling char array.

The C typedef of the function is:

```
typedef bool (*get_VariableInfoFunc)(int *, char * *, int *, int *);
```

It`s usage is like:

```
pnVariableIdArray = new (nothrow) int[numVars];
pcVariableName = new (nothrow) char*[numVars];
for (int i = 0; i < numVars; i++)
{
    pcVariableName[i] = new char[100];
}
pnUnVariableIdArray = new (nothrow) int[numVars];
pnVariableType = new (nothrow) int[numVars];
res = get_VariableInfo(pnVariableIdArray, pcVariableName, pnUnVariableIdArray, pnVariableType);
```

My C# Signature is:

```
[DllImport(AUTODYNResultsApiDll, EntryPoint = "get_VariableInfo", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetVariableInfo(
    int[] pnVariableIdArray,
    IntPtr[] pcVariableName,
    int[] pnUnVariableIdArray,
    int[] pnVariableType);
```

I use it like:

```
var stringPointers= new IntPtr[numVars];
for (int i = 0; i < numVars; i++)
{
    by[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
}
GetVariableInfo(pnVariableIdArray, stringPointers, pnUnVariableIdArray, pnVariableType);
```

and then back to string with:

```
var strings = new string[numVars];
for (int i = 0; i < numVars; i++)
{
    strings[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(by[i]);
}
```

Is there a nicer way doing this without freeing the Memory of the pointer. Just copy the char array as string array?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a few problems with your code as it stands:

1. The calling convention is `cdecl`, you need to include `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` in your attribute.
2. You set `SetLastError = true`, but the unmanaged function surely does not call `SetLastError`. If that is so, remove `SetLastError = true`.
3. You call `AllocHGlobal` but there is no matching call to `FreeHGlobal`, and so the memory is leaked.
4. Your assumption that no string will exceed a length of 100 (including null terminator) seems brittle, and at risk of buffer overflow.

As far as the main body of your question goes, the marshaller won't marshal an array of strings for you. Your current approach, subject to the provisos above, is the correct way to tackle the problem.